# Image based authentication

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is it possible to create a image based authentication system using the images encoded base64 ? in php or java...i jus want to know is it possible ?..and if it is possible can i get a briefing how should i do it ?? m really looking forward to do it .

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAA......
<img width="110" height="58" title="" alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAYABgAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm9s.......>
```

Comment: Sure.  How you load your images is completely separate from what you need to do with them.  Just beware the limitations of base-64 encoded resources.

Comment: Please provide more details. How is this image-based authentication system supposed to work? If you are the user, what do you see? What do you do?

Comment: it is possible but you did not show us the php code so hard to say... but you can use google's recaptcha or there are many other alternatives to this

Comment: What's the advantage/reasoning of using Base64 as opposed to files?

Comment: ya ..i am planning to give images to a user when they register and they should upload it to authenticate to gain access to the members area ...../ or i will use it as second layer after the username and pass is verified user should upload an image or select his image from the images displayed on the page .....is any of these possible ? thanks in advance

Comment: i dont knw the code and thats the problem as i dnt know how should i code it ...i jus want to use image to authenticate so thought of base64 as its long and tough to copy .

Comment: Basically i jus want to use the base64 as its long and complicated enough to make it secure and its unique as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to you that instead instruct the user to upload the image to authenticate him in the system, do the following.

Allow the user on the client side to select an image ,but instead of uploading the image and sending the image to the server , just calculate a hash(checksum) of the image in the client side, and send this hash(checksum) to the server. You can check if the file the user select is  identical to the one you have in the server by calculating the hash(checksum) on both files and if the hashes match, then you are sure than the user selected the right image.
Also i would suggest you to do something, else. There is the possibility that a sniffer(man-in-the-middle) can get the hash sent by the client and use it to authenticate it self. I would like to put some salt on the hash before sending it in order to get a cyphered string representation of the file hash before sending it.

Comment: Nice Idea ..thanks ..i would go wid calculating the hash on the client side and den using php decoding and den sending it to the server :-) but still will have to find out a way to do this ..but alteast got and doable idea :-) .....thanks alot !